# Casting reference variable without the double parentheses

Tags: java

Given the below two classes :

```
class A {}

class B extends A {
    int b;
}
```

Based on the following operators precedence table : http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html.

Both operators `()` and `.` have the same priority and they evaluated from left to right (associativity).

```
A a = new B();
assert (B)a.b == 0;
```

the above code snippet should compile and asserts successfully as the parentheses operator is evaluated first (casting reference `a` to type `B`) then accessing the casted reference's `b` member variable which returns a value of `0`.

Why is the above statement isn't the case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the `()` *Parentheses* in precedence 15 with the `( type )` *Unary type cast* in precedence 13.

The `.` *Member selection* in precedence 15 is higher than the type cast, so `(B)a.b` means `(B) (a.b)`, which is why you need to write `((B) a).b` to get what you want.

[image: part of precedence table]

Answer (score 3):

Those parentheses are a *unary type cast*, which has lower precedence than `.` member selection.

```
Precedence   Operator    Type                     Associativity
----------   --------    ----                     -------------
15           ()          Parentheses              Left to Right
             []          Array subscript
             .           Member selection

14           ++          Unary post-increment     Right to left
             --          Unary post-decrement

13           ++          Unary pre-increment      Right to left
             --          Unary pre-decrement 
             +           Unary plus
             -           Unary minus
             !           Unary logical negation
             ~           Unary bitwise complement
             ( type )    Unary type cast
```